# PHP Слияние многомерных массивов (уникальные значения)

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два многомерных массива:

```
 $array1 = array(
0 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"65"),
1 => array("cancelled" => "1", "id"=>"33"));

$array2 = array(
0 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"11"),
1 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"27"),
2 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"65"));
```

Как их элегантно слить, чтобы вышел массив с элементами с первого массива и второго, но все значения были уникальными, не повторялись?

Если применить $array3=array_merge($array1,$array2); то получится:

```
$array3 = array(
    0 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"65"),
    1 => array("cancelled" => "1", "id"=>"33")
    2 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"11"),
    3 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"27"),
    4 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"65"));
```

А нужно

```
$array3 = array(
    0 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"65"),
    1 => array("cancelled" => "1", "id"=>"33")
    2 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"11"),
    3 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"27"));
```

П.С. Уникальность значения можно определить и по полю массива значения 'id' - в моем случае, если id одинаковые то и значения одинаковые

Comment: ну дак отфильтруйте получившийся результат выкинув повторные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае, если не важно когда будет осуществляться проверка дубликатов, то отфильтровать повторные значения можно и после слияния массивов. Например, сделать это можно следующим образом.

Исходные данные:

```
$array1 = [
            ["cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"65"],
            ["cancelled" => "1", "id"=>"33"]
        ];

$array2 = [
            ["cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"11"],
            ["cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"27"],
            ["cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"65"]
        ];
```

Слияние и отсев повторов с помощью дополнительного ассоциативного (по `id`) массива.

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);

$result = [];
foreach($array3 as $v){
    if(isset($result[$v['id']])) continue;   // повтор элемента

    $result[$v['id']] = $v;
}
$result = array_values($result); //Если нужны ключи от 0 до N.
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот как я сделал, но тут двойной цикл и проверка до слияния:

```
$array1 = array(
    0 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"65"),
    1 => array("cancelled" => "1", "id"=>"33"));

$array2 = array(
    0 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"11"),
    1 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"27"),
    2 => array("cancelled" => "0", "id"=>"65"));

foreach($array1 as $key1=>$value1){ //Собираем ID по первому массиву
    foreach($array2 as $key2=>$value2){ //Собираем ID по второму массиву
        if($value2["id"]==$value1["id"]) {//Есть ли одинаковые
            unset($array2[$key2]);//Удаляем если есть одинаковые
        }
    }
}
print_r(array_merge($array1, $array2));//Сливаем и выводим
```